# how to close all forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

log.vb

```
Public Class log
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "bassam" And TextBox2.Text = "bassam" Then
            Me.Hide()
            msgbox1.Show()
        Else
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

msbox1.vb

```
Public Class msgbox1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the form `msgbox1`,  I want to close the form `log` when i press `Button1`, but it just closes the `msgbox1`. How can I close all the forms?

Comment: How many Forms have you? Do you want to exit your application? What is the value of the Shutdown mode option in the application page of your project?

Comment: `it just closes the msgbox1` what else would you expect `Me.Close` to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to close the whole application just call `Application.Exit()`.